# COUNT e SUM com 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de gerenciamento de TI.
Tenho 3 tabelas:
**computers, offices, office_keys**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo:

```
offices
______________________________________
id      | 1
version | Home & Business 2016


office_keys
_______________________________________
id        | 1
office_id | 1
key       | AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEE


computers
_______________________________________
id            | 1
name          | DESKTOP
office_key_id | 1
```

O campo **quantity** da tabela **office_keys** representa o número de vezes que aquela chave pode ser usada em computadores (office standard).

Eu quero fazer uma query que traga todas as versões do office, a soma da quantidade das keys (quantity) e soma de quantas chaves estão sendo usada (somente a soma).

Por exemplo:

Se eu tiver 4 chaves de office 2016 e 2 computadores utilizando 2 dessas chaves,
ou se eu tiver 3 chaves de office 2013 e 3 computadores utilizando essas 3 chaves, quero receber:

```
Office   |    Quantidade   |   Em uso
2016     |    4            |   2
2013     |    3            |   3
```

Tentei fazer isso:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
offices.id, offices.version,
SUM(office_keys.quantity) AS quantity,
COUNT(computers.id) AS in_use
FROM
offices
LEFT JOIN office_keys ON office_keys.office_id = offices.id
LEFT JOIN computers ON computers.office_key_id = office_keys.id
GROUP BY
offices.id
```

Mas a somas não estão certas por causa das linhas duplicadas.

Como posso resolver isso?
Obrigado!

Comment: Ou retire o campo offices.version da select-list ou acrescente este campo na cláusula GROUP BY (GROUP BY offices.id, offices.version).

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso, mas não resolve... A soma da quantidade continua dando errado por causa dos registros duplicados. 
Quero fazer a soma das quantidades e o count dos computadores agrupados pelo office.

Comment: Você já avaliou se o uso da cláusula DISTINCT na função de agregação atende a suas necessidades?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!

Só precisava fazer uma subquery dentro do JOIN:

```
SELECT 
offices.id,
offices.version,
SUM(sub.quantity) as quantity,
SUM(in_use)
FROM offices
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        office_keys.office_id,
        office_keys.quantity,
        COUNT(computers.id) as in_use
    FROM
        office_keys
    LEFT JOIN computers ON computers.office_key_id = office_keys.id
    GROUP BY office_keys.id
) as sub 
ON sub.office_id = offices.id
GROUP BY sub.office_id
```